# Нужна помочь написать код в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан список чисел. Не используя функцию len определения количества
элементов в этом списке и не используя цикл по коллекции, определить:

a) количество элементов в списке;
b) сумму элементов в списке;
c) значения наибольшего отношения (доли) среди элементов.

Comment: Если нельзя использовать цикл по коллекции, можно в цикле `while True` перемещаться с помощью `next`

Comment: **numList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
quantity = str(numList).count(',') + 1** - я эти костылем решил. Правда если в списке будут строки с запятыми, то работать не будет

Answer (score 1):

Я решил с помощью обработки исключений:

```
def mylen(list):
    tmp = 0
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            tmp = l[i] #пытаемся присвоить переменной tmp значение списка
            i+=1
        except IndexError: #если i вышло за размаеры списка - завершаем цикл
            break
    return i




l = [1,2,3,4]
i = mylen(l) #теперь i - кол-во элементов
print("Количество элементов равно ",i)
```

Длина у вас есть, дальше справитесь сами

UPD добавил нахождение суммы:

```
tmp = 0
sum = 0

while tmp < i:
    sum += l[tmp] #просто прокручиваем список
    #и прибавляем к sum его значения один за другим
    tmp += 1
print("Сумма элементов равна:",sum)
```

Comment: у меня не получается еще сделать суму элементов

Comment: @Denver99 добавил, но постарайтесь разобраться. Это часто встречается в задачах

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Denver99 Сделал код более оптимальным, вчера получилось не очень)

Answer (score 1):

Допустим есть:
    ar = [1,2,3,4,5]

**a)** Как альтернативный подход можно взять индекс последнего элемента + 1:
**    ar.index(ar[-1]) + 1** где ar[-1] последний элемент списка.

**b)** Условием задачи не запрещено использовать встроенную функцию sum():

**sum(ar)**

или без неё, но с циклом:

while ar:
  result += ar.pop()
return result

**c)** Специальные функции в Python вщзвращают минимальный и максимальный элементы в списке соответственно:
**max(ar) - min(ar)**